# MySQL Query equals column name

Tags: mysql

I have a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
`Table1`.`UniqueID` as `parent_id`, 
`Table1`.`OtherField`, 
(SELECT SUM(`SomeRandomField`) FROM `AnotherTable` WHERE `SomeRandomField` NOT LIKE '%Something%' AND `UniqueID` = `parent_id`) AS `DataIWant`
#Other selects, a couple of joins etc here
```

In My Scenario - `Table1.UniqueID` as (Parent_Id) contains a unique integer

In My Scenario - `AnotherTable.UniqueID` contains both the unique integer from table 1 - but also may contain other unrelated junk that starts with this integer.

The problem I have is that this query as it stands is that when `parent_id` is 1400, the sub-select will still return the sum of SumRadomField including UniqueID '1400A2D45A'

How do I go about exact matching on this field?  Having searched - I havent found anything that works yet including double quoting the UniqueID, adding various escape characters, double-equals etc.

Comment: Can `AnotherTable.UniqueID` have many `Table1.UniqueID`s? Is it `1:m` or `1:1`

Comment: table1.uniqueID is unique, table1.uniqueid can appear several times in anothertable

Comment: Does the `Table1.UniqueID` value always comes with 4 digits?

Comment: no, its an autoincrement integer.  Currently up to 6 digits, may get longer with time.  AnotherTable is a varchar 20 and contains all kinds of junk from varying iterations before my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CONCAT` and `LIKE` instead of the equals operator (`=`).

Replace

```
... `UniqueID` = `parent_id` ...
```

with

```
... `UniqueID` LIKE CONCAT(`parent_id`, '%') ...
```

---

The complete query would be

```
SELECT 
    `Table1`.`UniqueID` AS `parent_id`,
    `Table1`.`OtherField`,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(`SomeRandomField`)
        FROM
            `AnotherTable`
        WHERE
            `SomeRandomField` NOT LIKE '%Something%'
                AND `UniqueID` LIKE CONCAT(`parent_id`, '%')) AS `DataIWant`
-- and your joins...
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go but it makes sense.  It'll take a few hours to put in and test properly - but I'll let you know as soon as I have anything

Comment: @Fazer87 No worries, take your time.

Comment: spot on... near enough.  because i only want exact matches, i ended up using `= CONCAT(parent_id, '')` but it worked perfectly.  Thankyou so much, you've saved my ass.  Now onto the next problem.  If I ever get my hands on the person who wrote this originally, I'm going to beat them with a sharp stick.

Comment: @Fazer87 You are welcome, don't forget to accept the answer and upvote!

Comment: Done and Done - you've absolutely definitely earned it.  Thankyou again